# Running C# code in VS Code only has an option of Run Tests, not also Run Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

The following is the meniu that I see in my VS code:

[image]

Also, when I run the code from the upper right triangle it returns error:

[image]

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you go to the terminal and type `dotnet run`?

Comment: Is this only this .cs file or do you have a csproj, actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle button in the upper right corner is the `Run Code` command of *Code Runner*. If you want to execute or debug the code, please refer to the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugging). It is more correct to use the official extension pack.